# Curve on Lorentz manifold

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

If $\alpha : [0,B) \rightarrow M, B \leq \infty$, is an extendible, piecewise smooth (nonspacelike curve) in a Lorentz manifold, then $\alpha$ has a finite length.

Any hints on how to show this? I know what all the words mean, but I have trouble seeing the trees. I tried writing out the arc length integral and playing around with the limits (using extendibillity), but it got me nowhere.

Comment: In a Lorentzian manifold, geodesics maximize the arc length of a like wise path. I don't know if continuity of close sets to closets is a valid statement in a pseudo-metric manifold. If does, I don't see why this have to be limited to time like curves...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to treat the case of finite B, by reparametrizing.

But in this case, extending $\alpha$ past B, you can see that the length of $\alpha$ from $0$ to B is an integral of a continuous function ($\|\alpha'(t)\|$) over the compact set $[0, B]$, which is finite.

Comment: Integrating over $[0, B]$ is the same as integrating over $[0, B)$, *as long as the former exists*, since points have measure zero.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like I was on the right track though :)